# Extremely fast hash function with collisions allowed

Tags: c++, c, linux, hash, x86-64

My key is a 64 bit address and the output is a 1 byte number (0-255). Collisions are allowed but the probability of them occurring should be low. Also, assume that number of elements to be inserted are low, lets say not more than 255, as to minimize the pigeon hole effect.

The addresses are addresses of the functions in the program.

Comment: what's the distribution of your addresses? it's going to help with the answers, what addresses are they?

Comment: Talkol - Addresses of the functions in the program

Comment: If your hash has 256 values possible, the number of elements should be far less than 256 if you want to avoid collisions. With 255 elements, collisions will be numerous.

Comment: This isn't well-defined at the moment.  What's the distribution?  What collision rate is tolerable?

Comment: Should the hash be secure against predicting the output of a given input (on multiple iterations of the same program)?

Comment: At the very best, the chance of a collision will be 1 in 256. With less than ten elements you'll be odds on for a collision, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Comment: Actually, your first element will have 0 chance of a collision but it increases rapidly from there. 2 readers of this post almost certainley share a birthday.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I've corrected my rather optimistic assertion but the sentiment stands (27th April.)

Answer (score 3):

```
uint64_t addr = ...
uint8_t hash = addr & 0xFF;
```

I think that meets all of your requirements.

Comment: it all depends on the distribution of the addresses, it could easily turn out to be horrible

Comment: Trying to hash 255 keys to 256 values will probably be horrible in any case. This seems like the fastest possible solution.

Comment: @talkol Agreed; however, +1 anyway, since taking the eight low-order bits is about as fast as it gets and, if addresses are uniformly distributed mod 256 (not an unreasonable assumption), it is also about as good at avoiding collisions as it gets.

Comment: addresses do not distribute uniformly, I'm pretty sure a function address can't be odd, probably has to be divisible by 4

Comment: newer gcc will lay out functions so they're aligned on 16 byte  boundaries

Comment: I only posted this answer because the question was ill-defined.

Comment: And malloc() blocks are almost always 16 byte aligned on 64 bit platforms.  But Alex is right, the requirements are such that a "fancy" hash function is probably overkill -- it doesn't take much work at all to get even distribution over 256 possible values.  Just pick some middle bits then: `(((long)addr)>>5) & 0xff`

Comment: @AndyRoss We don't actually know he wants to hash malloc blocks. He could be getting a page aligned block, dividing it up into objects and hashing the addresses of said objects...

Comment: @AndyRoss - you can't be sure of the alignment on every platform, so you'll end up throwing the max lsb's. this is bad because the lowest "good" bits offer the maximum variation and you don't wanna throw them

Comment: Great sense of humor, loved it !

Answer (score 3):

I would XOR together the 2 LSB (least significant bytes), if this distribues badly, then add a 3rd one, and so forth

The rationale behind this is the following: function addresses do not distribute uniformly. The problem normally lies in the lower (lsb) bits. Functions usually need to begin in addresses divisible by 4/8/16 so the 2-4 lsb are probably meaningless. By XORing with the next byte, you should get rid of most of these problems and it's still pretty fast.

Comment: XORin with the higher byte achieves the same effect, is as quick, and is a bit simpler since you're not sure how many bits to shift right anyways.. because the lower "good" bits provide the most variation so you won't want to throw them out if you don't have to

Answer (score 1):

Function addresses are, I think, quite likely to be aligned (see [this question, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909563/why-should-code-be-aligned-to-even-address-boundaries-on-x86)). That seems to indicate that you want to skip least significant bits, depending on the alignment.

So, perhaps take the 8 bits starting from bit 3, i.e. skipping the least significant 3 bits (bits 0 through 2):

```
const uint8_t hash = (address >> 3);
```

This should be obvious from inspection of your set of addresses. In hex, watch the rightmost digit.

Comment: If the functions are all in the same dso or all in the main program, the high bits will all be the same too. I suspect just bits 4-18 are significant.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
uint64_t data = 0x12131212121211B12;

uint32_t d1 = (data >> 32) ^ (uint32_t)(data);
uint16_t d2 = (d1 >> 16) ^ (uint16_t)(d1);
uint8_t  d3 = (d2 >> 8) ^ (uint8_t)(d2);

return d3;
```

It combined all bits of your 8 bytes with 3 shifts and three xor instructions.

Comment: very nice :) but a bit overkill

Comment: Could benefit from avoiding 16-bit and 8-bit arithmetic operations on an x86-64 or x86 processor as you don't need to reduce the width down to 8 bits until the very end. Also the last shift would probably be better done with a greater shift right, such as (8+3) or (8+4) because of function alignment as mentioned by an earlier poster.