# What is ALIGN in arch/i386/kernel/head.S in linux source code

Tags: linux-kernel

In the head.s file present in linux source code at path `arch/i386/kernel/head.S`, `ALIGN` is used as seen in code snippet given below after `ret` instruction. My question is that what is this `ALIGN`, as per my knowledge it is not instruction, not assembler directive, so what is this and why it is used here?

You can get the code of `head.S` at site given below:

http://kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/arch/i386/kernel/head.S?v=2.4.0

Path: `arch/i386/kernel/head.S`

```c
/*
 * We depend on ET to be correct. This checks for 287/387.
 */
check_x87:
    movb $0,X86_HARD_MATH
    clts
    fninit
    fstsw %ax
    cmpb $0,%al
    je 1f
    movl %cr0,%eax
    xorl $4,%eax
    movl %eax,%cr0
    ret
    ALIGN            /* why ALIGN is used and what it is? */

1:  movb $1,X86_HARD_MATH
    .byte 0xDB,0xE4
    ret
```

Comment: forcing next instruction to be aligned to the next word boundary?

Comment: @user3528438 Not really the **word** boundary, it's more complicated. On modern CPUs it's often 16 bytes alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `ALIGN` is just a macro, defined at [include/linux/linkage.h](http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/include/linux/linkage.h#L53) file:

```c
#ifdef __ASSEMBLY__
#define ALIGN __ALIGN
```

And `__ALIGN` definition depends on architecture. For `x86` you have next definition (in kernel 2.4), in [the same file](http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/include/linux/linkage.h#L40):

```c
#if defined(__i386__) && defined(CONFIG_X86_ALIGNMENT_16)
#define __ALIGN .align 16,0x90
#define __ALIGN_STR ".align 16,0x90"
#else
#define __ALIGN .align 4,0x90
#define __ALIGN_STR ".align 4,0x90"
#endif
```

So in the end `ALIGN` macro is just `.align` asm directive, and it's either 4- or 16-bytes alignment (depending on `CONFIG_X86_ALIGNMENT_16` option value).

You can figure out your `CONFIG_X86_ALIGNMENT_16` option value from [arch/i386/config.in](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/i386/config.in?v=2.4.37) file. This value actually depends on your processor family.

---

Another question is why such an alignment is needed at all. And my understanding is next. Usually CPU can access only aligned addresses on bus (for 32-bit bus the address usually should be aligned by 4 bytes, e.g. you **can** access 0x0, 0x4, 0x8 addresses etc., but you **can't** access 0x1, 0x3 addresses, because it would lead to [unaligned access on bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Unaligned_access)).

But in your case I believe it's not the case, and alignment is done only for performance reasons. Basically this alignment allows CPU to fetch `1:` section more quickly:

```c
ALIGN

1:  movb $1,X86_HARD_MATH
    .byte 0xDB,0xE4
    ret
```

So it seems like this `ALIGN` is just some minor optimization.

See also next topics:

[1] [Why should code be aligned to even-address boundaries on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909563/why-should-code-be-aligned-to-even-address-boundaries-on-x86)

[2] [Performance optimisations of x86-64 assembly - Alignment and branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113995/performance-optimisations-of-x86-64-assembly-alignment-and-branch-prediction)

Comment: __ALIGN is macor but i am talking about just ALIGN

Comment: and if ALIGN is also macor where can i get source code of macor ALIGN

Comment: Yeah, `ALIGN` is also a macro, it turns into `__ALIGN`. See the first `#define` in my answer. So `ALIGN` basically **is** `__ALIGN`. And source code for both `ALIGN` and `__ALIGN` can be found at `include/linux/linkage.h`, as it was mentioned in my answer above.